# WebStorm LiveEdit only working for some elements

Tags: html, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, liveedit

I started using webstorms live edit and it all seems to be working fine except for the fact that it doesn't live edit some of the html.
For example I have a navbar using bootstrap. Anytime I change the links or brand title it makes the changes instantly. However when I add a new element in the main container I have to refresh the browser for it to show up and the live edit still doesn't work on it.

here is the html  http://pastebin.com/j6UHTfC1

Very strange.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a sample html file with that you can reproduce the problem? Unfortunately, wasn't able to reproduce it so far. If you can, you can report a new issue on: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB Thank you!

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara i added a link to the HTML
the part that is not live updating is marked with <-- sdfdfs

Comment: Thanks, reproduced and created the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22518 Please follow it for updates.